# What's the difference between smb.service and smbd.service?

Tags: systemd, samba

I see some people are using `smb.service`:

ex:
[https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/getting-started-samba#:~:text=Samba%20enables%20Linux%20%2F%20Unix%20machines,evolved%20and%20added%20more%20capabilities](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/getting-started-samba#:%7E:text=Samba%20enables%20Linux%20%2F%20Unix%20machines,evolved%20and%20added%20more%20capabilities).

```
# systemctl enable smb

# systemctl start smb
```

What's the different to `smbd.service`?

Comment: well, what does the smb.service do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smb.service` is the name of the service as shipped by the Samba project. The Debian Samba packages ship these files as `smbd.service` (and `nmbd.service` etc.); other distributions shipp them as-is.

Thus on Fedora-based distributions, including RHEL, the service file is `smb.service`, whereas in Debian (up to Debian 11) it’s `smbd.service`, but the two are equivalent. The `samba` package in Debian 12 [will ship synonyms](https://salsa.debian.org/samba-team/samba/-/commit/d100752088f44e87e04112d3f550312904a2e0fe), so both `smb.service` and `smbd.service` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, some distros use 'smb' when starting the Samba smbd daemon, others use 'smbd'.